# Replace with RegExp only outside tags in the string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a strings where some html tags could present, like

```
this is a nice day for bowling <b>bbbb</b>
```

how can I replace with RegExp all **b** symbols, for example, with **:blablabla:** (for example) but **ONLY** outside html tags?

So in that case the resulting string should become

```
this is a nice day for :blablabla:owling <b>bbbb</b>
```

**EDIT:** I would like to be more specific, based on the answers I have received. So first of all I have just a string, not DOM element, or anything else. The string may or may not contain tags (opening and closing). The main idea is to be able to **replace anywhere in the text except inside tags**. For example if I have a string like

```
not feeling well today :/ check out this link <a href="http://example.com">http://example.com</a>
```

the regexp should replace **only** first `:/` with real smiley image, but should not replace second and third, because they are inside (and part of) tag. Here's an example snippet using the regexp from one of the answer.

```js
var s = 'not feeling well today :/ check out this link <a href="http://example.com">http://example.com</a>';
var replaced = s.replace(/(?:<[^\/]*?.*?<\/.*?>)|(:\/)/g, "smiley_image_here");
document.querySelector("pre").textContent = replaced;
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

It is strange but the [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sI0nW9/2) shows that it captured the correct group, but the same regexp in replace function seem not to be working.

Comment: Use a parser, not regex.

Comment: ^^ What Ed said. [You cannot reliably handle HTML with just a regular expression](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/157247). You just can't. You might think "Oh, my use case is simple enough that..." It isn't. It just isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex itself to replace all `b`s with `:blablabla:` is not that hard:

```
.replace(/b/g, ":blablabla:")
```

It is a bit tricky to get the text nodes where we need to perform search and replace.

Here is a DOM-based example:

```js
function replaceTextOutsideTags(input) {
  var doc = document.createDocumentFragment();
  var wrapper = document.createElement('myelt');
  wrapper.innerHTML = input;
  doc.appendChild( wrapper );
  return textNodesUnder(doc);
}
function textNodesUnder(el){
  var n, walk=document.createTreeWalker(el,NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,null,false);
  while(n=walk.nextNode())
  {
       if (n.parentNode.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'myelt')
        n.nodeValue =  n.nodeValue.replace(/:\/(?!\/)/g, "smiley_here"); 
  }
  return el.firstChild.innerHTML;
} 

var s = 'not feeling well today :/ check out this link <a href="http://example.com">http://example.com</a>';
console.log(replaceTextOutsideTags(s));
```

Here, we only modify the text nodes that are direct children of the custom-created element named `myelt`.

Result:

```
not feeling well today smiley_here check out this link <a href="http://example.com">http://example.com</a>
```

Comment: If you just have a direct access to the document (say, it is an HTML document opened in the browser), you do not have to use a custom element, just make sure it is under `<body>` tag.

Comment: I am not parsing DOM. I just have a string, that's all. The idea basically is to replace everywhere in the string, except inside tags.

Comment: My code is for parsing an HTML string with a dom parser. It will replace substrings in the text outside of tags.

Comment: not the ideal solution, I am trying to find regexp-based only solution. Can you examine snipped that I have attached to initial question? Maybe you could correct it to make it work.

Comment: Most answers suggesting regex based solutions for HTML parsing are likely to be downvoted. I am trying to avoid it. All I can do now is prettify my code a bit so that it becomes more readable.

Comment: I split the code a bit so that it is more readable. Even if you say it is "not the ideal solution", it is the only correct way to modify arbitrary HTML: parse with a parser and only modify the plain text you need.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var input = "this is a nice day for bowling <b>bbbb</b>";
var result = input.replace(/(^|>)([^<]*)(<|$)/g, function(_,a,b,c){
    return a
    + b.replace(/b/g, ':blablabla:')
    + c;
});
document.querySelector("pre").textContent = result;
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

You can do this:

```
var result = input.replace(/(^|>)([^<]*)(<|$)/g, function(_,a,b,c){
            return a
            + b.replace(/b/g, ':blablabla:') // you may do something else here
            + c;
});
```

Note that in most (no all but most) real complex use cases, it's much more convenient to manipulate a parsed DOM rather than just a string. If you're starting with a HTML page, you might use a library (some, like [my one](https://github.com/Canop/groumf), accept regexes to do so).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a regex like this : (Just for a simple data not a nested one)

```
/<[^\/]*?b.*?<\/.*?>|(b)/ig
```

[[Regex Demo]](https://regex101.com/r/dE7fC4/1)

---

If you wanna use a regex I can suggest you use below regex to remove all tags recursively until all tags removed:

```
/<[^\/][^<]*>[^<]*<\/.*?>/g
```

then use a replace for finding any `b`.

Comment: correct me if I am wrong but the first group of **/<[^\/]*?b.*?<\/.*?>|(b)/ig** already finds (marks, if I follow the demo link) occurences inside tags. If I use this regexp in replace function, it will replace inside tags also.

Comment: @kaytrance At first regex you will capture `b` outside the tag that you can replace just captured part by using a substitution of `\1` ;).

Comment: could you provide an example, maybe just by forking your demo?