# Non-capturing group ignored by regex101.com

Tags: javascript, regex

A question arrived from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33151416/replace-with-regexp-only-outside-tags-in-the-string) regarding regular expressions. I am stucked to understand the difference in results I get, and I am worrying if there may be a bug in parsing libraries or something else.

So the initial question was to replace all `:/` **in given string**, except ones that may be inside tags in that given string. The initial string is

```
not feeling well today :/ check out this link <a href="http://example.com">http://example.com</a>
```

I have tried to use the following regexp to replace only the first `:/` in given example. To skip occurances inside tags non-capturing group is used:

```
/(?:<[^\/]*?.*?<\/.*?>)|(:\/)/g
```

What was most surprising is that this regexp gives different results depending on tool/language being used. Here's a brief summary of results I got

- [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/kY6vI5/1) shows **1** match!!
- [regexpal.com](http://regexpal.com/) shows **2** matches
- [regexr.com](http://regexr.com/3c0et) shows **2** matches
- [regextester.com](http://www.regextester.com/) shows **2** matches

Below also a javascript snippet to check the same regexp, and the result, as you can see also is different from what supposed to be - 2 matches -> 2 replacements will occur.

```js
var s = 'not feeling well today :/ check out this link <a href="http://example.com">http://example.com</a>';
var replaced = s.replace(/(?:<[^\/]*?.*?<\/.*?>)|(:\/)/g, "smiley_image_here");
document.querySelector("pre").textContent = replaced;
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

It seems that non-capturing group is simply ignored.
So, what is wrong, why results differs and what is the correct regexp to solve initial question?

Comment: seems not to be true because in particular section called "match information" only one match is being displayed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

regex101 also returns 2 matches, as you can see on the label:

[image: total matches]

and the 2 different colors in the text

[image: colors]

It is indeed a bit confusing if you look at the `MATCH INFORMATION` section. However, that is only intended to show you **captures**, not necessarily matches:

[image: captures]

---

You may as well test this by replacing each match with some string:
https://regex101.com/r/kY6vI5/2

---

The [non-capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) is not ignored. It simply doesn't create a capture, but it is in fact matched.

Comment: so how do I then use it with .replace to replace only the first *smile* in this example? It seems for me that the question is unsolvable

Comment: You need a nested function to replace only if the group creates a capture: http://jsfiddle.net/tvcu9r4r/ ... However, don't use regex to parse HTML, [use DOM instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33152209/5290909)